# How to perform realtime multiplication with select box?

Tags: javascript

I have a question about realtime calc.

I would like to make realtime multiplication. I searched web and found this gentleman's awesome code so I have a question.

http://jsfiddle.net/nnnnnn/5FpWC/

I would like to change as select box.

First of all User type number then select one of box's product name
then this calc program calc first value and select box's value.

I wrote below code but it doesn't work. Could you teach me right code please?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".txtMult input").keyup(multInputs);

  function multInputs() {
    var mult = 0;
    // for each row:
    $("tr.txtMult").each(function() {
      // get the values from this row:
      var $val1 = $('.val1', this).val();
      var $val2 = $('.val2', this).val();
      var $total = ($val1 * 1) * ($val2 * 1)
      $('.multTotal', this).text($total);
      mult += $total;
    });
    $("#grandTotal").text(mult);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr class="txtMult">
  <td>
    <input name="txtEmmail" class="val1" />
  </td>
  <td>
    <select name="txtEmmail" class="val2" />
    <option value="100">product A</option>
    <option value="150">product B</option>
    <option value="160">product C</option>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td>
    <span class="multTotal">0.00</span>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr class="txtMult">
  <td>
    <input name="txtEmmail" class="val1" />
  </td>
  <td>
    <select name="txtEmmail" class="val2" />
    <option value="211">product D</option>
    <option value="365">product E</option>
    <option value="449">product F</option>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td>
    <span class="multTotal">0.00</span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: After putting your code on snippet it seems to be working perfectly fine based on the approached you have explained. Try this: First select the product and then enter the value... you will realize that it works. But i you just enter the value and then select different product the calculation doesn't happen because it is bound to `keyup` event.

Comment: Dear @Mosia Thabo Thank you very much for answering me. Oh my!  yes. it worked perfectly. but I would like to calc what you said. User want to change diffrent product...  Is there way to fix this?

Comment: Sure, Too bad I'm answering late. Jony has provided the answer. Good luck!

Comment: Dear @Mosia Thabo I really appreciate your kindness. Thank you very much for quick responce and helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the corrections dear friend
You can run right here

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
 
       $(".txtMult input").keyup(multInputs);
       $(".select").on("change", function(){ //usando class 
    multInputs()
});
    
       function multInputs() { 
           var mult = 0;
           // for each row:
           $("tr.txtMult").each(function () {
               // get the values from this row:
               var $val1 = $('.val1', this).val();
               var $val2 = $('.val2', this).val();
               var $total = ($val1 * 1) * ($val2 * 1)
               $('.multTotal',this).text($total);
               mult += $total;
           });
           $("#grandTotal").text(mult);
       }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
 <tr class="txtMult">
            <td>
                <input name="txtEmmail" class="val1"  />
            </td>
            <td>    
                <select name="txtEmmail" class="val2 select" />
                <option value="100">product A</option>
                <option value="150">product B</option>
                <option value="160">product C</option>
                </select>   
            </td>
            <td>
                    <span class="multTotal">0.00</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="txtMult">
            <td>
                <input name="txtEmmail" class="val1"  />
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="txtEmmail" class="val2 select" />
                <option value="211">product D</option>
                <option value="365">product E</option>
                <option value="449">product F</option>
                </select> 
            </td>
            <td>
                <span class="multTotal">0.00</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
       </table>
```

Comment: Dear @Jony Alan Thank you very much! This is amazing. Thank you for helping me

Comment: Imagine friend, when you need just call, Brazil here

Comment: Dear @Jony Alan Thank you very much .that's so kind. Thank you.